# Disable certain ListViewItem from being selected - WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listviewitem

I have a list view which is data bound to a class called FolderItem. I simply set the DataContext in the code behind.

Based on certain conditions I want to disable certain `ListViewItems` so that it cannot be selected. Do I have to drill down the tree to obtain the items I want to disable? If so, any links or pointers as to how to do it would be helpful. Or is there any other way to do this?

**EDIT**

```
  <ListView x:Name="FolderListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}" SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged"  IsTapEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single" AllowDrop="False" CanDragItems="False" IsSwipeEnabled="False">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <Grid Height="60" Width="380" Margin="0,0,0,1" >
                       <Grid x:Name="ItemGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="380" Height="60" >                                          
                            <TextBlock x:Name="titleTextBlock"  Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding FolderText}" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="25" >
                            </TextBlock>
                       </Grid>                                
                  </Grid>
              </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

This is the ListViewItemStyle1

```
   <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsItemEnabled}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ItemBgBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMargin}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
   </<Style>
```

I have bound IsEnabled property with class. But it seem to have no effect. Is it because I have defined `<ListView.ItemTemplate>??`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Windows Phone version of the `ListView` control. But I see that `ListViewItem` has an `IsEnabled` property. Have you tried simply setting that to `false`? Alternatively, you could handle the `SelectionChanged` event, checking for items that should not be selected and unselecting them if they are selected.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have updated the question with code. I tried binding the IsEnabled value. But it seem to have no effect..

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough specific knowledge to know for sure whether that should work. What you did _looks_ correct to me; i.e. you've created the necessary `DataTemplate` for your items, it looks like your model object has an `IsItemEnabled` property to which you've bound the `ListViewItem.IsEnabled` property. But it was only just a guess on my part that the `IsEnabled` property would affect whether the item could be selected. Did your attempt have _any_ effect at all on the item? Did it at least change the appearance, or anything?

Comment: Just study this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207023(v=vs.105).aspx How databinding is working with class objects. And then define a bool property in class item(Recording) and bind that to IsHitTestVisible of Listviewitemtemplate first outtermost control(grid). it will work, i don't have to make an example for you right now.